# How to exclude Interceptor call for a welcome file (Context Root) in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I want to exclude interceptor call when user tries to access the application with context root. How can we do this kindly help me on this. I have tried as below. `SSAPP` is my context root but it is not working:

```
<mvc:interceptor>
    <mvc:mapping path="/**" />
    <mvc:exclude-mapping path="/images/*" />
    <mvc:exclude-mapping path="/javascripts/*" />
    <mvc:exclude-mapping path="/stylesheets/*" />
    <mvc:exclude-mapping path="/SSAPP/" />
    <bean class="SessionInterceptor" />
</mvc:interceptor>
```

Comment: How did you define this context root? Your servlet mapping defined on `/SSAPP`? Maybe you should try just `/` instead of `SSAPP`.

Comment: Could you post the entire context configuration? Did you enclose the `<mvc:interceptor>` into `<mvc:interceptors>`?